# Need guidance with AWS website backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mysql-workbench, aws-api-gateway

I have a website that I am trying to have the web form connect to a MySQL database running on Amazon's RDS to post and retrieve information. I'm an absolute beginner with code but have managed to get myself this far (creative3c.org). I've had coworkers and friends offer some help, but their knowledge doesn't extend to everything I was told I would need (AWS API Gateway, Lambda--anything else?).

I've been pulling my hair out for a week looking through tutorials, articles, and step-by-step guides but so many presume extensive knowledge on the viewer or they all talk about what I don't need (like phpmyadmin--and php won't work for S3 or Lambda).

Am I jumping too far into the really complex stuff? The person that told me to go the AWS route is certified and brilliant with code--but unfortunately they are fickle, busy, and aren't a good teacher to distill their knowledge. I don't know if I should have gone with something simpler. If you view the website, you'll probably understand how basic it is.

I'm stuck and really stressed about finishing this website and appreciate the help to get me in the right direction! I feel I'm so close! I'm really good at scaling up from a small example of exactly what I need--I just need that initial example!

Comment: Ultimately you have a couple of ways to go.  You can use API gateway and Lambda to interface with RDS or you could have traditional architecture with an application server running on an EC2.  That would be what you describe with PHP.  What programming environments are you familiar with?  Regardless of the serverless vs. traditional server you'll need to write some back end code to handle what you want.  I would argue that serverless is a bit harder to get started with than a traditional server.

Comment: I agree totally with @stdunbar. You don't need to worry about most of the AWS technologies if you just pick a standard "web application reading a database" model. If you are just starting out I suggest you do that. You simply write a standard application and deploy it to AWS. You don't mention what kind of web app you are writing but PHP usually goes hand in hand with MySQL. This is often called 'LAMP'. Here's the AWS guide in creating a LAMP server: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html. This does not require Lambda, API gateway, or any of that stuff

Comment: .. and here's a link on building a simple LAMP app... but you seem to have done both of these things since you already have something running online. http://www.jessewolcott.com/building-a-simple-lamp-web-app/

Comment: Thanks for the quick support everyone! I will look into these. I've also started looking into websites that can provide this as a service quickly and painlessly. That search isn't turning out so well, but I'm sure I'm not the only one out there with this issue!

Comment: What did you write your existing web site in? What technology do you want to use? You need to answer these things to get anywhere. AWS is just the platform that you deploy it to

Comment: A month ago, I came into this project with no knowledge at all. I've since picked up on html and php (mostly through ample tutorials and W3School). I'm not sure the technology. Because of its simplicity, I felt SQL was good enough and I didn't need the capabilities of NoSQL. Beyond that, I'm not sure what other technologies I could need.I've been coming across some sources that point out the beast that is AWS. I think I got into it thinking it would be something else. I've found a comfortable approach with BlueHost and its relation to MySQL and phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pleased to hear that you've learnt so quickly. All the terminology floating around can be very confusing. Just remember: AWS is just the platform you deploy to. It can be as simple and complicated as you want it to be

I'm not an AWS expert but here's my birdseye view

You could build an entire running website on your laptop then simply deploy that wholesale to a LAMP server that you've created up in AWS. Now you have a web application running in AWS, without using any of the AWS jargon (beanstalks, lambdas...)

Thats when you would follow this link to provision your server: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

Or you could put the database piece of your application into RDS (a database on the cloud) then put the web application piece in a seperate web server then configure those two servers to talk to each other.

You have a web site but it's now running on two seperate machines

Or (I'm a bit hazy on this) for the web app you could instead deploy bits of your web code to lambda and stick them all together

In all cases you can apply 'elastic beanstalk' to automatically grow and shrink the computers running your site.

Like I said it can be as simple and complicated as you want it to be - and you don't need it to be complicated so the BlueHost option is fine.